# How can I bind a function without tkinter?

Tags: python, events

I want to bind a function `Aha()` without using any tkinter widgets.

```
def Aha(event):
    if event.keysym=='space':
        print('Aha!')
bind('<Key>', Aha)
```

An error shows up and it says bind is not defined(because it's missing the tkinter widget like `tk.` in front of `bind()`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If `bind` is in the `tk` module, you need to specify that or specifically import it from there (`from to import bind` if that's the correct thing).

Comment: @ndc85430 it says cant import bind from __init__ function in class.